# Вложенный запрос SQL с тремя таблицами

Tags: sql, foxpro

Есть три таблицы:

- `Orders`, информация об услуге (`service`) и исполнителе (`employee`).
- `Employees`, информация об исполнителе (`employee_id`).
- `Services`, информация об услуге (`service_id`, `service_price`).

Нужно найти исполнителей с зарплатой выше среднего.  Во вложенном запросе я хочу найти зарплату каждого исполнителя: просуммировать по имени исполнителя цены всех услуг из заказов, которые он исполнил.

Далее, из этой промежуточной выборки хочу выбрать всех исполнителей, чья зарплата выше среднего.  Пишет, что синтаксическая ошибка.  Может, что не так делаю, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```sql
SELECT B.employee_name, B.sum;
    FROM(;
    SELECT Employees.employee_name, SUM(Services.service_price) AS sum;
        FROM ;
        WHERE Employees.employee_id = Orders.employee ;
            AND Services.service_id = Orders.service ;
        GROUP BY Employees.employee_name ;
        ORDER BY Employees.employee_name;
        ) AS B;
    WHERE B.sum > AVG(B.sum);
    ORDER BY Employees.employee_name;
```

Comment: Это что за диалект такой? ';' в конце каждой строки? Обычно же в конце всего запроса

Comment: Если использовать конструктор запросов, то он делает так же -- ставит ; после каждой введенной строки....

Comment: Но это что то ненормальное. ни в одном диалекте sql, известных мне, точек с запятой в середине запроса быть не может. как минимум удалите из. после этого проверяйте по отдельности подзапросы. И еще во внутреннем подзапросе сортировка не имеет смысла

Comment: SELECT Employees.employee_name AS employee_name,;
  SUM(Services.service_price) AS sum;
 FROM ;
     Employees,;
    Services,;
    Orders;
 WHERE  Employees.employee_id = Orders.employee;
   AND  Services.service_id = Orders.service;
 GROUP BY Employees.employee_name;
 ORDER BY Employees.employee_name

Внутренний запрос выполняется.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов и Mike  Я загуглил, _Visual FoxPro_ действительно использует точки с запятыми в конце строк.  См., например, [_PDF_](http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/ConferenceSessions/Using%20VFP%209s%20SQL%20Commands.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали ни диалект *SQL*, ни версию СУБД!  Вот 
переносимая версия, работающая в *PostgreSQL* 9.6+ и
*SQLite* 3.22+:

```sql
WITH employee_service_prices(employee_id, service_price) AS (
  SELECT employee_id, service_price
    FROM employees
         LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.employee = employees.employee_id
         LEFT JOIN services ON orders.service = services.service_id
)
SELECT employee_id
  FROM employee_service_prices
 GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING SUM(service_price) > (
  SELECT AVG(service_price) FROM employee_service_prices
)
```

Этот запрос находит всех сотрудников, чей суммарный доход строго больше
среднего дохода по всем заказам всех сотрудников.

---

Учитыввая странную и устаревшую СУБД, возможно вам больше подойдёт
вариант с двумя явными подзапросами без *CTE*:

```sql
SELECT employee_id
  FROM (
         SELECT employee_id, service_price
           FROM employees
                LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.employee = employees.employee_id
                LEFT JOIN services ON orders.service = services.service_id
       ) AS t
 GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING SUM(service_price) > (
  SELECT AVG(service_price)
    FROM employees
         LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.employee = employees.employee_id
         LEFT JOIN services ON orders.service = services.service_id
)
;
```

Если и это не сработает, то у меня всё.

Comment: Спасибо. Я работаю в VFP.

Comment: @Светлана _Visual FoxPro_ — софт очень старый, запрос может не сработать.  Попробуйте и отпишитесь.  Если сработает, можете проголосовать и отметить ответ как верный.

Comment: A command was used without a clause that was required by the Visual FoxPro syntax. 
Вот такая ошибка теперь.

Comment: @Светлана А если попробовать точки с запятыми проставить как у вас в примере?

Comment: Я это тоже сделала. Ругается на что-то другое.

Comment: @Светлана  Добавил второй вариант и сделал ближе к вашей схеме.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, ошибка с subquery. Буду разбираться с синтаксисом.